# small e RSA attack with float value

Tags: floating-point, rsa

For a crypto class, I am trying to implement a "small e attack" by computing the plaintext as pow(ciphertext,1./e).

I have done it when the result is an integer, but when I get a float, I do not know how to convert that result to a string of characters that represents my plaintext.

```
e1 = 3
n1 = 131776503472993446247578652375782286463851826883886018427615607890323792437218636575447994626809806013420405963813337101556738852432247872506699457038044621191649758706817663135648397013226104530751563478671698441687437700125203966101608457556637550910814187779205610883544935666685906870199595346450733709263
cipher1 = '\x04\xacq#E/\xf4X\x126\xef\xc6\xb1\xfc\x10p*\x98P\xde\x089K\x16y0\xfa\xde\x9f\x05\x15+\xa3\x0f\xbc3\xd1t\xe7\x9a\x1b\x04m\xa1\x12\x96\x18Y\xf9\xc95\xce\x19 E\xfa\xe1\xb5\x8a\xd5\xf2\x99\xa6"<\xcb\x1a\xd0\xce=\x91\xfbw\t\xb5'
```

I can convert cipher1 to bits and then to an integer (call it cipher1_int) so I can run

m1=pow(cipher1_int,1./e1)

and the result is

```
4.23125987157e+59 <type 'float'>
```

can someone help me?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What output do you expect from that? Is the hexadecimal representation of the float value meant to contain the ASCII plaintext of the decrypted plaintext? `4.23125987157e+59` becomes `0x7F800000`, which doesn't seem very useful (it's basically "infinity").

Comment: Crypto calculations are normally done using integers and modulo arithmetic. E.g 1/2 = 3 (mod 5). Since 3*2=6=1 (mod 5)

Answer (score 2):

These calculations need to be done using modulo arithmetic, more specifically mod n1. To get an integer that represents the plaintext ...

1. Calculate the integer `1/e1 mod n1`.  (Look up calculating [modular inverses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse))
2. Calculate the integer `pow(cipher1, 1/e1 mod n1) mod n1` (Look up [modular exponents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation))

This will give you an int that you can convert to plaintext

Comment: Note to readers: In this answer, `1/e1 mod n1` is not the classic “one divided by e1”. It is “Some integer x such that x*e1 is congruent to 1 modulo n1”. (Roughly speaking, two numbers are congruent modulo n1 if they have the same remainder when divided by n1.) An `x` with this property acts like a multiplicative inverse to `e1`, because, for any integer `t` that is relatively prime to `n1`, `t*e1*x` is congruent to `t` modulo `n1.` But you cannot find `x` using classic division.